# My car wont start and is silent when turning ignition, but lights, radio etc will come on. What is the most likely culprit?

Tags: car, ignition, starter, fuse, mazda-3

When trying to start my car the lights, radio, and all auxiliary components will turn on, but the car is silent and not trying to turn over. However, if I shift my car out of park and back into park a few times, it will eventually turn over without problem. I have recently checked my battery and it still has plenty of juice so I can rule that out. What might some other possible causes of this be?

Comment: **Update, the car will start in neutral with no problems

Comment: Perhaps Neutral safety switch, sometimes when these go bad they prevent starting in park, but neutral still works. IT should stop you starting the card in any drive gear